# Not coupling domain to Infrastructure layer in Hexagonal Architecture asp.netcore webapi

Tags: domain-driven-design, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Hexagonal Architecture, the applicationuser entity which is extending asp.netcore identity is in the domain layer, (so coupling domain to Infrastructure layer), along with skill entity(A applicationuser can have multiple skills and a skill can belong to multiple applicationuser) what idea do you have about the applicationuser being a domain entity and what approach could we use to keep it in the domain but at the same time not couple that layer to the infrastructure layer?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the domain is it being unaware of technology-specific details such as asp.net core's Identity.

So from this perspective, ApplicationUser (as you described) actually belongs to infrastructure layer, thus cannot belong to domain layer.

Now, you can use a simple OOP pattern to decouple domain from infrastructure, e.g.:

```
// Domain layer (abstraction)
interface IIdentity
{
    string Email { get; }
}

// Infrastructure layer (implementation details)
class AspNetCoreIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public AspNetCoreIdentity(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        this.User = user;
    }

    private ApplicationUser User { get; }

    public string Email => this.User.Email;
}
```

Hope that helped...